# display pyramid shape using a stack of rectangle in a relative layout

Tags: android, imageview, rect

I have 7 xml files in my drawable folder for drawing 7 rectangle in decreasing order of size.
Each xml file is the background resource of an imageview.This means I have 7 imageviews.

I used the relative layout to place them on top of each other in order of decreasing size, so that the smallest rectangle is on the top.

Here is the sample xml of one of the drawable xml file for rectangle:-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">

  <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
        android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="90"/>
        <solid
        android:color="#FFFF0000"></solid>
         <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#cccccc" />

            <padding android:left="50dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="50dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

Although I got the stack of rectangles by using attribute **"android:layout_above"**.But the rectangles are aligned at one side.But I want them not to align on either of the side and appear as reduced edges on both sides.

Basicaly I want all the rectangles to be aligned at the centre so that the reduced edges of the top rectangle is seen on bot side of the bottom rectangle.But I am not finding any attribute of imageview which can help me.

This is my relative layout which is inside a horizontal scroll view:-

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/desert">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/camel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/puppet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/sun"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/hand"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stone1"
            android:background="@drawable/stone1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sun"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stone2"
            android:background="@drawable/stone2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/stone1"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sun"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stone3"
            android:background="@drawable/stone3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/stone2"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sun" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stone4"
            android:background="@drawable/stone4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_above="@id/stone3"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sun"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stone5"
            android:background="@drawable/stone5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/stone4"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sun" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stone6"
            android:background="@drawable/stone6"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/stone5"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sun" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stone7"
            android:background="@drawable/stone7"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/stone6"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sun" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried padding option ? With suitable values for padding, you might be able to get"pyramid" effect.

Comment: @Shash316 I have put different values of left and right padding for each rectangle's xml file.Basically I am decreasing them by 5 dp in each file.But still an unable to get the pyramid look...

Answer (score 0):

Show us the relative layout, you want to set either of these values on your imageview's (rectangles):

```
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

or

```
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Comment: I have put the relative layout as part of my qustion.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set `android:gravity` in your relative layout

Comment: android:gravity option is not displayed for my imageview which is in a relative layout.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is the RelativeLayout I was referring to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#attr_android:gravity.  It doesn't looks like there's a class called ImageView derived from this class.

Comment: @ruchira - don't rely on the auto complete to see what you can do, check the API. gravity would work on the imageview but you would have to set the width or height to fill_parent

Comment: @lightblade,@Blundell setting the gravity to center_vertical is not making the stack look like a pyramid.they are aligned on one side and the other side shows decreasing sizes.

Comment: I think you're looking for "center" and not "center_vertical". "center" aligns it's children both horizontally center and vertically middle.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by setting **"android:layout_marginLeft"**  to approppriate values i.e. smallest rectangle was farthest from left and biggest rectangle was nearest and each adjacent rectangle had a difference of 5 dp of the above parameter.And I got the pyramid :)